# Webbrowser control not getting focus

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, setfocus, mxgraph

I am facing a weird issue with getting a web browser control into focus.
I have a web browser control added onto a user control.The user control is being used in a windows host control form inside another application.

Now the web browser control is navigated to a page hosting mxgraph application.

When I select any specific shape on the graph the key events are not being triggered for any keys. (arrow keys, delete or any character key). I tried the following options:
1. On mouse up event - set tab index of the container element (div) to -1. Call focus() on the container element.
2. On mxEvent.CHANGE event of the selection model- set tab index of the container element (div) to -1. Call focus() on the container element. Calling 'addSelectionCell' function to add the cell explicitly to selection array.

Surprisingly the key board events are working when I add a debugger or an alert inside the mxEvent.CHANGE event handler.

Can anyone help me getting the browser control to focus and get the key events working?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue - On Change event of the mxgraph selection model, setting focus to the web browser control (its the web browser control that needs focus and not the container) resolved the issue.